# SyntaxHighlighter not working in the blogger preview mode

Tags: blogger, blogspot, syntaxhighlighter

I had been using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) along with Google Blogger to highlight code and xml on my [blog](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/). It used to work in the preview mode and also once the post has been published. All of sudden it stopped working in the preview mode, but works once the blog has been published. I am not sure if any changes have been made to the SyntaxHighlighter or to the Google Blogger.

How to get SyntaxHighlighter work in the preview mode also? I want to make sure that the blog post looks good with SyntaxHighlighter in the preview mode before publishing it.

Comment: SyntaxHighlighter cannot work under preview mode.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original query, it used to work in preview mode also and all of a sudden it stopped. I am not able to figure out why. I had been using it for more than a year.

Comment: I see. Look forward to the answer.

Comment: As work around temporarily created another blog in Blogger, publish the post from it, make sure it looks good and then finally copy the HTML to the blog of interest. Made the temporary blog invisible to the bots and public.

Comment: Also post this question on the official blogger forum  under "something is broken".They might be able to help.

Comment: I have been using prism syntax highlighter since forever and it works in the preview mode, in case you want to switch to that. Never worked with the syntax hightligher, so I cannot really help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Prism](http://prismjs.com/)Prism is a lightweight, extensible syntax highlighter, built with modern web standards in mind. It’s used in thousands of websites, including some of those you visit daily.